# Stop rebuilding fragment again and again

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In my application I am giving navigation drawer by these lines of code

```
 switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.list_view_container, fragment).commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.current_event:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.college_events:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.national_events:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.workshops:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.trainings:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Launching " + menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.companies:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.talents:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.games:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.submission:
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                        case R.id.about:
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                }
```

Each time new selection goes on fragments get rebuilt again and again I just want to just pause each fragment at its last state and wake up on their selection without getting rebuilt.

Comment: I  gave just one fragment for  just  now

Comment: hold on I'll give you a detailed answer now

Comment: please mark as answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use something like this:

```
               case 1:
                    if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ranking")==null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder,
                                new RankingFragment(), "ranking").
                                addToBackStack("ranking").
                                setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                .commit();

                    } else {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("ranking", 0);
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: You are great hats off. Thanks

Comment: And one thing more I have to press back again and again if I open all the fragment the I have to press back =no. of the fragments in opened. So I want something which can remove previous fragment from User (Your code is just replacing the one fragment on another)and what I want one Fragment at once. Can you solve that too?

Comment: Sorry I was out, you can use this: "getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()" to pop the whole stack and then add the new fragment. did you mean this?

Comment: if you want to always have 1 fragment in backstack, before your 'switch() {...}' use "getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()"

Comment: I just want to confirm that Fragments would not rebuilt again and again ? if I have just one Fragment in backstack

Comment: they'll be rebuilt unless you keep them in stack, even keeping them in stack doesn't promise you too keep them all the time, but if you just keep one each time you want to access other fragments they'll be rebuilt again and again

Comment: So I want some thing so that the previous fragments should not be visible

Comment: previous view is there on last view And it looks awful

Comment: Anything there to replace view ? just view

Comment: give a background color to root of your fragment layouts and make sure to set android:clickable="true", this way they'll be always under top fragment and not visible.

Comment: Sorry the answer was unchecked by mistake and I never see that